# _curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal

Tags: manjaro, rxvt, ncurses

A lot of people have been getting the following error message when using curses in python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bertil/anaconda3/bin/vd", line 152, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/bertil/anaconda3/bin/vd", line 130, in main
    vdtui.run(*sources)
  File "/home/bertil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/visidata/vdtui.py", line 2841, in run
    ret = wrapper(cursesMain, sheetlist)
  File "/home/bertil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/visidata/vdtui.py", line 2831, in wrapper
    return curses.wrapper(setupcolors, f, *args)
  File "/home/bertil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/curses/__init__.py", line 73, in wrapper
    stdscr = initscr()
  File "/home/bertil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/curses/__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

I have been able to solve the problem by running:

```
export TERMINFO=/bin/zsh
export TERM=linux
```

However, I have to do it every single time I open a new terminal, which gets very annoying in the long run, especially because I look to use tools like visidata a lot (which generated the above error).

I am on **Manjaro Linux with i3**, and my terminal is **urxvt**.

I have realized that I only actually need the `export TERM=linux` part.

I have tried adding it to .profile, but`export TERM=linux`  it doesn't help.

Adding `export TERM=linux` to .bashrc solves the problem, but I am worried about other things not working when changing TERM from the default `rxvt-unicode-256color`.

Comment: A more interesting question may be why `TERM` is not correctly set.  Also, `TERMINFO` should not point to the binary executable shell, it should point to a _directory_ where the terminal definition files are found. It is seldom necessary to set `TERMINFO`.

Comment: Interesting. I just realized that I only actually need the `export TERM=linux` part. I have tried adding it to .profile, but it doesn't help. Will update answer

Comment: It would be beneficial to know what shell you are using. If it's `zsh`, then it would not read your `.profile` (it uses `.zprofile`), It's slightly surprising that `TERM` isn't properly set, so you may want to say something about your environment too (e.g. the desktop environment and/or how the terminal is started).

Comment: Thanks for the help Kusalananda. I was just able to solve the problem by adding `export TERM=linux` to my .bashrc. Should I still be worried about TERM not being set? I am not aware which shell I am using though I'll try figure out. Thanks!

Comment: I am using bash.

Comment: If I dont set TERM to linux, TERM is set to `rxvt-unicode-256color`

Comment: Looks like manjaro doesn't package urxvt, and its terminal description is [see FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#no_urxvt) not provided by ncurses.  Setting `TERM=linux` is not going to work.  Try `TERM=rxvt`.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Both `export TERM=rxvt` and `export TERM=linux` work for me. I am worried about adding it to .bashrc though. Is it something I should be worried about?